# Convert JSON list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas, dataframe

I have very large json data with the following syntax:

```
[
 {
   "origin": 101011001,
   "destinations": [
    {"destination": 101011001, "people": 7378},
    {"destination": 101011002, "people": 120}
   ]
 },
 {
   "origin": 101011002,
   "destinations": [
    {"destination": 101011001, "people": 754},
 }
]
```

[enter image description here][1]

My goal is the convert the data to a pandas dataframe which I then want to convert to sql to store as a table in my postgresql database.

I want to create a pandas dataframe like this:

```
origin    destination  people
101011001 101011001    7378
101011001 101011002    120 
101011002 101011001    754
```

Right now, I can only get columns 'origin' and 'destinations' where destinations is a list containing both the destination and people values, using *pandas.read_json()*.

How can I achieve the above dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_normalize`. This should work as intended:

**Edit** (from `string` to `list of dicts`, then `json_normalize`)

```
data = """[
 {
   "origin": 101011001,
   "destinations": [
    {"destination": 101011001, "people": 7378},
    {"destination": 101011002, "people": 120}
   ]
 },
 {
   "origin": 101011002,
   "destinations": [
    {"destination": 101011001, "people": 754}]
 }
]"""

from pandas import json_normalize
import json

data = json.loads(data)
df = json_normalize(data,"destinations",['origin'])
df.head()
```

Comment: My data is from a webapi, which I used requests.get(url), and with 60000+ values. What method should I use to load the data for ur code?

Comment: `json_normalize` requires the data to be a `list` of `dicts` - which is what your data looks like (in example) - how does it look in reality?

Comment: my data looks like the above but its not a dictionary since I'm getting it from a webapi in json format

Comment: So, a `string`? Use `import json;data = json.loads(data)` to convert it to the format above!

Comment: sorry I am quite new at json so I have no idea what many things mean

Comment: can you check the `type` of your data there using `type(data)` and see if it's `string`? Or share the website you are talking about?

Comment: originally i was using this: response = requests.get("url") then pd.read_json(response.text) which is not right but I'm not sure how to load the data otherwise

Comment: I can't share the website since it is from a secured network which I can only access through a vpn :(

Comment: I will add a screenshot of the data to the post

Comment: Ok! `type(response.text)` should be a `string` - so, you can just use the modifications I made - `data =  json.loads(response.text)` and then go on.

Comment: Great! Can you please accept it as answer then? (if you haven't already!)