# How can I concatenate triple-double quote to a variable in python to convert JSON list to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838743/convert-json-list-to-pandas-dataframe) question I want to convert a list of json to a pandas dataframe and convert this:

```
[
 {
   "origin": 101011001,
   "destinations": [
    {"destination": 101011001, "people": 7378},
    {"destination": 101011002, "people": 120}
   ]
 },
 {
   "origin": 101011002,
   "destinations": [
    {"destination": 101011001, "people": 754},
 }
]
```

To:

```
origin    destination  people
101011001 101011001    7378
101011001 101011002    120 
101011002 101011001    754
```

However, my json list is a variable and change through a loop because I used multithreading to get a list of json data. Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838743/convert-json-list-to-pandas-dataframe), I must add """ at the beginning and end of the json list. But, here it is a variable not a string. How can I add """  to the json list?
Is there any easier way to convert a json list into a pandas dataframe?

The main code is:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=14) as executor:
    for url in cid_str:
        sleep(0.1)
        processes.append(executor.submit(download_file, url))
 for index, task in enumerate(as_completed(processes)):
        jdata = task.result()

jload = json.loads('"""' + jdata + '"""')
df = json_normalize(jload,"destinations",['origin'])
```

Comment: Can use only `df = json_normalize(L,"destinations",['origin'])` ?

Comment: I have already edited the question and add my code. But it is not working!

Comment: hmm, so what is error `df = json_normalize(jdata,"destinations",['origin'])` ?

Comment: If I remove `jload = json.loads('"""' + jdata + '"""')` from the code:
Exception has occurred: KeyError x
'destinations'

Comment: Ok, `df = json_normalize(jdata)` ?

Comment: Super, can you test if in some column are not nested dictionaries or lists?

Comment: It worked. Because of a mistake, it was not working!
Now, it works.